# how to get iframe source code that is on different domain

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am able to get a 3rd party iframe component working on the site. 
But, I get a security Exception (not same domain) when I am trying to access its source code. Is there a way or workaround to get the source code of the iframe component?

```
document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Comment: you can't directly get the content of a cross site iframe - you can use code on both sites to "speak" with each other, but that requires co-operation from the 3rd party iframe (you can't get around security, that's why it's called security, because it makes the web more secure)

Comment: You can get the source code via the debugger or view/source in the browser, but you can't get access to it from Javasscript in another domain.  Browsers block cross origin access (without cooperation of the other frame) to avoid various types of deception and various types of attacks in web pages.